# Multi column index implementation

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

Does anyone know how the multi column index is implemented in (B-Tree or whatever)?

is the key concatenated or it is something like the kd-tree?

Answer (score 5):

Answer here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.( which is why its not marked answered)  The questioner is mostly concerned about how the implementation approach , eg. Rather than saying it can be done using a B-tree ( or minmax tree) , it would be helpful if you provided information about how keys are formed using multiple columns in such a way that they are ordered , so that a B-tree can be used.